# How can do compare of the array object in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
    {
  "_id": ObjectId("5efb3d1a9ed984485c1a0d25"),
  "monthlyVideoStatistics": [
    {
      "likes": 60,
      "_id": ObjectId("5efc5aa1f232f87f944501e1"),
      "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-03-31T23:59:59.999Z"),
      "month": 3,
      "year": 2020
    },
    {
      "likes": 80,
      "_id": ObjectId("5efc5a7eaeded6697c688049"),
      "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-04-30T23:59:59.999Z"),
      "month": 4,
      "year": 2020
    },
    {
      "likes": 75,
      "_id": ObjectId("5efcac3c6f91307578019717"),
      "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-05-31T23:59:59.999Z"),
      "month": 5,
      "year": 2020
    }
  ]
}
```

I am having a JSON object like this.
Here I need to compare the likes in **month** 4(April) were greater or less than in **month** 3(march)
Is it possible to get the particular array **object id** or like greater true or false something like that?

here a month, likes are referred to as the field name.

so if need to compare likes in month 3 with month 4, if it will be greater then return the document data or some value like **greater**

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the expected result? I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: I never compared any data till now, so I have no idea.
My requirement is like, imagine I need to find the progress of likes, the month of 4(April) compare to month3(march). I need to know the month 4 likes will be greater or smaller

Comment: Again, please provide a sample of desired output.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: if it will greater then return data else don't return any data